# Javascript module pattern, ajax functions callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var ajaxStuff = (function () {

    var doAjaxStuff = function() {
      //an ajax call
    }

    return {
       doAjaxStuff : doAjaxStuff 
    }

})();
```

Is there any way to make use of this pattern, and fetch the response from a successful ajaxcall when calling my method? Something like this:

```
ajaxStuff.doAjaxStuff(successHandler(data){
    //data should contain the object fetched by ajax
});
```

Hope you get the idea, otherwise I'll elaborate.

Comment: why not just `$.ajax('url').success(function (data) {...});`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:
1. Add a parameter to the doAjaxStuff function. 
2. When invoking doAjaxStuff, pass in an anonymous function (or the name of a function)

```
var ajaxSuff = (function () {

var doAjaxStuff = function(callback) {
   // do ajax call, then:
   callback(dataFromAjaxCall);
}

return {
   doAjaxStuff : doAjaxStuff 
}

})();

// calling it:

ajaxStuff.doAjaxStuff(function(data){
    //data should contain the object fetched by ajax
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just let `doAjaxStuff` accept a callback:

```
var doAjaxStuff = function(callback) {
    // an ajax call
    // Inside the Ajax success handler, call
    callback(response); // or whatever the variable name is
}
```

Depending on your overall goals, you could also use [*deferred objects*](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) instead (or in addition). This makes your code highly modular. For example:

```
var doAjaxStuff = function() {
    // $.ajax is just an example, any Ajax related function returns a promise 
    // object. You can also create your own deferred object.
    return $.ajax({...});
}

// calling:

ajaxStuff.doAjaxStuff().done(function(data) {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to read the jQuery docs for [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). You could make a call as simple as:

```
$.ajax('/path/to/file').success(function (data) {
    doStuff();
})
```